# Вывод нужных полей из JSON (php)

Tags: php, json

Добрый день. На сайте есть скрипт, который получает и выводит ответ в формате json. Необходимо вывести только конкретные поля:

Пример JSON

```
{
    "server_time":1517236803,
    "test":
        {
            "test1" : 123,
            "test2" : 123,
            "test2" : 123
        }
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Как обратиться именно к этому "полю" (без его значения) и сделать вывод , вне зависимости от размера полученного JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

```
$test = json_decode($json_object)->test;

foreach($test as $k => $v) {
    echo $k . " : " . $v . "\n"; 
}
/*
output:
    test1 : 123
    test2 : 123
    test3 : 123
*/
```

Comment: Размер вырастает, добавляется "test4" и бух!

Comment: @Other спасибо за замечание, поправил